# How to open add contact page on android platform in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm making an app using flutter that uses the contacts(using contact_services plugin) from user's phone. Thus it needs as well to give the ability to add a new contact using the system default add contact page. However there isn't such functionality in contacts_services. What is the way using plugin or existing contact_services plugin to open the add new contact page?

```
void openAddContacts() async{
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  final AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
    action: 'ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION',
    category: 'ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE',
  );
  await intent.launch();
 }
}
```

Comment: I am searching for this feature as well and didnt find anything at all. Quite sad that it isnt easy to use such a simple and basic functionality.

Comment: have you got the answer, please reply

Answer (score 1):

This may help you : https://github.com/differenz-system/Addressbook.Flutter
Or if you xant to dive deeper and want to understand the mechanism under the hood, I suggestion you to use Platform Channel to communicate with native codes. Here is an example proposed by Google for address-book : https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/darttutorial

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

if you use this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service you can look full working example here https://github.com/lukasgit/flutter_contacts/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

Add permissions

Android #

Add the following permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

iOS #

Set the NSContactsUsageDescription in your Info.plist file

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>  
<string>This app requires contacts access to function properly.</string>
```

And after you can use code from the example by link above.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But the example in the link is an in-app add contact page. What I'm trying to achieve something exactly like what whatsapp does when you tap on "New Contact" button in select contact

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully understand your question. I made small research - you are right, right now there is no easy way to add "New Contact" with Native functions.
It is possible to do, the best way is to make a new package and implement this functionality for Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Basically you have to invoke the method from MainActivity.kt and we will use Intent to open the default contact app, just like what WhatsApp does.

First, on your .dart file create the channel that will connect to the MainActivity.kt, like this :

`static const openCreateContact = MethodChannel('com.example.yourApp/openCreateContact');`

Also create a function that will invoke the method that we will later implement in MainActivity.kt, you can then call it on onPressed():

```
 onPressed: () async {
 String phone= "+212 666 000 111";
 String name = "John Doe";
await openCreateContactMethod(name , phone);
},

Future openCreateContactMethod(name, phone) async {
await openCreateContact.invokeMethod('openCreateContact', {
  'name': name,
  'phone': phone,
});
```

}

Then, head towards MainActivity.kt, it will look something like this:

```
package com.example.yourApp

import android.content.Intent
import android.provider.ContactsContract
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
private val channel = "com.example.yourApp/openCreateContact";

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,channel).setMethodCallHandler{
            call, result ->

         
            if (call.method == "openCreateContact") {
                val name = call.argument<String>("name")
                val phone = call.argument<String>("phone")
                openCreateContact(name!!, phone!!)
                result.success(true)
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }

    }

    fun openCreateContact(name: String, phone: String) {
        // Create a new Intent to open the Contacts app with a pre-filled contact form
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
        intent.type = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE

        // Set the contact fields using the data provided by the Flutter app
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, name)
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, phone)

        // Launch the Contacts app with the pre-filled contact form
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```